# How to download Apache Slider (incubating)?

Tags: apache, download, slider

I can not find any way to download slider.
(I am working on hive on tez with llap)

Version INFO:

Latest release: 0.92.0-incubating

Website:

https://slider.incubator.apache.org/downloads/

BTW: the website will redirect to 
http://incubator.apache.org/projects/slider.html

How to download Apache Slider (incubating)?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs. Download form here.

https://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/slider/0.92.0-incubating/